# impossible to modify encapsulated variables

Tags: c#, winforms

*Consider the following code.*

```
using System.Drawing;

public class Element
{
    public static Point position1;
    private static Point position2;

    public static Point Position2
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }
}

class Drawing
{
    public Drawing()
    { 
        Element.position1.X = 0; //Correct
        Element.Position2.X = 0; //Incorrect
    }
}
```

Why can not the value of `position2.X` be changed through `Element.Position2.X`?

Because of this I am obliged to do :

```
Point newPoint = new Point (0, 0);
Element.Position2 = newPoint;
//Or : Element.Position2 = new Point (0, Element.Position2.Y);
```

- Why is not it simply possible to access the value of `position2.X` as with `position1.X` but using `Element.Position2.X` ?
- Do you know any other way to solve the problem?

Comment: Because `Point` is a `struct` and not a `class`

Comment: There not actually being a `position` field could cause access issues, I imagine.

Comment: Are you sure your code compiles? `position` variable not declared

Comment: Getter will return copy of your original encapsulated member. That's why creating new Point works, but updating will update a copy, not original value.

Comment: It's amazing what you'll find, if you just [search Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+cannot+modify+because+not+a+variable) for the error message the compiler gives you when you try to do something wrong. As explained in the many duplicate questions already on SO, your property `Position2` isn't returning a variable; it's returning a temporary copy of the value, so modifying the `X` property of that value will have no effect. The "other way to solve the problem" is exactly as you already know: assign the entire value back.

Comment: Oh okay, I'll do it from now on, I'll think about the error message that the compiler gives. - @PeterDuniho

Comment: "Updating will update a copy, not original value."
Can you explain please ? I do not understand well. - @Fabio

Comment: "Are you sure your code compiles? position variable not declared"
Sure it does. I have also thought about it and tried the code and it compiles very well. I don't know why but I think it works because of the `static` modifier.

Answer (score -2):

Correctly define the public or private operator

```
  public class Element
    {
        private static Point position1;
        private static Point position2;

        public static Point Position1
        {
            get { return position1; }
            set { position1 = value; }
        }
        public static Point Position2
        {
            get { return position2; }
            set { position2 = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked. The OP is trying to understand why the compiler won't let them modify `Position2.X`. The question has nothing to do with `public` vs `private`